# Axial inconsistency of pandas.diff

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [True, False]})
```

The following code works:

```
df['col'].diff()
```

The result is:

```
0     NaN
1    True
Name: col, dtype: object
```

However, the code:

```
df.T.diff(axis=1)
```

gives the error:

```
numpy boolean subtract, the `-` operator, is not supported, use the bitwise_xor, the `^` operator, or the logical_xor function instead.
```

Is that a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing would appear to be at odds with the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) which clearly state:

> For boolean dtypes, this uses operator.xor() rather than operator.sub(). The result is calculated according to current dtype in DataFrame, however dtype of the result is always float64.

Also interesting is the following test:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [True, False], 'col2': [True, False]})

print("","df:",sep='\n')
print(df,df.dtypes,sep='\n')

print("","diff of df:",sep='\n')
res = df.diff()
print(res,res.dtypes,sep='\n')

print("","diff of df['col']:",sep='\n')
res = df['col'].diff()
print(res,res.dtypes,sep='\n')

print("","df.T:",sep='\n')
res = df.T
print(res,res.dtypes,sep='\n')

print("","diff(axis=0) of df.T:",sep='\n')
res = df.T.diff(axis=0)
print(res,res.dtypes,sep='\n')

print("","df.T.astype(object):",sep='\n')
res = df.T.astype(object)
print(res,res.dtypes,sep='\n')

print("","diff(axis=1) of df.T.astype(object):",sep='\n')
res = df.T.astype(object).diff(axis=1)
print(res,res.dtypes,sep='\n')

try:
    print("","diff(axis=1) of df.T:",sep='\n')
    res = df.T.diff(axis=1)
    print(res,res.dtypes,sep='\n')
except TypeError:
    print('got TypeError')
```

Output:

```
df:
     col   col2
0   True   True
1  False  False
col     bool
col2    bool
dtype: object

diff of df:
    col  col2
0   NaN   NaN
1  True  True
col     object
col2    object
dtype: object

diff of df['col']:
0     NaN
1    True
Name: col, dtype: object
object

df.T:
         0      1
col   True  False
col2  True  False
0    bool
1    bool
dtype: object

diff(axis=0) of df.T:
          0      1
col     NaN    NaN
col2  False  False
0    object
1    object
dtype: object

df.T.astype(object):
         0      1
col   True  False
col2  True  False
0    object
1    object
dtype: object

diff(axis=1) of df.T.astype(object):
        0   1
col   NaN  -1
col2  NaN  -1
0    object
1    object
dtype: object

diff(axis=1) of df.T:
got TypeError
```

If we change the column types to object using `astype()` before the call to `diff(axis=1)`, no error is raised and the result appears to cast the boolean values to int prior to performing the diff using integer subtraction.

However, as OP points out, this same operation **without** `astype(object)` raises the TypeError `TypeError: numpy boolean subtract, the` -`operator, is not supported, use the bitwise_xor, the`^ `operator, or the logical_xor function instead.`, **despite** the claim in the `diff()` docs that `For boolean dtypes, this uses operator.xor() rather than operator.sub()`.

Comment: Thanks, @constantstranger, for your answer. In fact, I have just tried: `True ^ False`, which returns `True`. So, according to the documentation, `df.T.diff(axis=1)` should return `True` too.

Comment: I have just filed a bug report: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/52579

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this behaviour is intentional as per [*GH15856*](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15856). Arithmetic operations `(+, -, *, /, etc.)` between boolean arrays in NumPy are not (*or not anymore?*) supported.

With [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html?highlight=diff#pandas.DataFrame.diff) on `axis=1`, pandas tries to compute the difference between consecutive elements along the columns axis (*which happens to hold booleans here because of the transposition*) and since NumPy is run under the hood to compute that, a `TypeError` is raised.

```
print(df.T)

        0      1
col  True  False

np.array(False) - np.array(True)

TypeError: numpy boolean subtract, the `-` operator, is not supported, use the bitwise_xor, the `^` operator, or the logical_xor function instead.
```

This can be counterintuitive, because the same operation when using Python boolean, succeeds :

```
False - True
# return -1
```

But @*seberg* explains why :

> This is a pretty old deprecation, although I do seem to remember some
> discussion about only deprecating the unary operator -False not True -
> True. **Note that Python booleans are different from NumPy ones**, they
> are practically integers. NumPy booleans behave much less like
> integers, if you add two booleans you get a boolean again, etc.

Comment: Thanks, @Timeless, for your answer. What intrigues me is that `df['col'].diff()` works fine. That is, following the logical of your answer, `df['col'].diff()` should produce the same reported error.

Comment: I agree but the difference is that in `df["col"].diff()`, we use [`pandas.Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) and in `df.T.diff(axis=1)`, we use [`pandas.DataFrame.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html). I think in the former, pandas uses Python booleans and in the latter, NumPy ones.

Comment: @Timeless actually, it appears that DataFrame.diff works fine for axis=0, and (as we can see even in OP's original question) the result is of type boolean, which must mean that a boolean operator (not subtraction) such as xor is being used - exactly as the DataFrame.diff docs assert (see my answer for link). It seems as though introducing axis=1 someone triggers the use of numpy subtraction logic on the boolean values (perhaps, following the logic in your comment, this is because for axis=0 it simply reuses the Series.diff() logic, and for axis=1 it attempts something different).